# What is the partition of the Set S induced by R in this example?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

A company makes charm bracelets with 4 charms: A, B, C, and D. There are 24 different orders they can enter the machine:

ABCD ABDC ACBD ACDB ADBC ADCB

BCAD BCDA BDAC BDCA CABD CADB

CDAB CDBA DABC DACB DBAC DBCA

BACD BADC CBAD CBDA DCAB DCBA

Once the charms are threaded on a bracelet many of the arrangements look the same. If the relation R on the set S of line arrangements with the rule (X,Y) ∈ R if arrangements X and Y look the same when threaded on a bracelet, what is the partition of the set S induced by R?

Would this be right?

The partition of the set S induced by R is 
{{ABCD, BCDA, CDAB, DABC}, {ABCD, BDCA, DCAB, CABD}, {ACBD, CDBA, DBAC, BACD},{ADBC, DBCA, BCAD, CADB}, {ADCB, DCBA, CBAD, BADC}}

Answer (score 0):

Almost.  Note that you can flip around a bracelet.

... or would a bracelet and its flipped counterpart not 'look the same'?  Then again, if I rotate a bracelet, one could argue that that does not look the same either ... Hmmm ... maybe you shpould look for some clarification on what 'look the same' exactly means ...

(BTW: you're missing $4$ orders...  Also, first entry of second set should be ABDC, and first entry of third set ACDB...)

Comment: "look the same" means the same is an equivalence relation and the charms of one are in the reverse order of the charms of the other, wouldn't there only be 5 subsets with 20 members?

Comment: @happysaint OK, so then you should get 3 groups of 8 ... (e.g. your first group of 4 is the flipped versions of the last group of 4)

Comment: Could it be 6 groups of 4? So: {{ABCD, DABC, CDAB, BCDA}, {ABDC, CABD, DCAB, BDCA}, for 2 groups and {ACBD, DACB, BDAC, CBDA}, {ACDB, BACD, DBAC, CDBA}, {ADBC, CADB, BCAD, DBCA}, {ADCB, BADC, CBAD, DCBA}}

Comment: If flipping a bracelet around means it still 'looks the same', then ABCD is the same as BCDA,CDAB, DABC, DCBA, CBAD, BADC, and ADCB. So, three group of 8. if flipping around means it no longer looks the same, you get 6 groups of 4.

Comment: I guessed what "look the same means" in my comment above and am confused now what it actually means. Wouldn't shifting letters to the next place, as with 6 groups of 4 'look the same'? For example from the first group of 4, ABCD is related to DABC, DABC is related to CDAB and CDAB is related to BCDA, they are reflexive, symmetric, and transitive as an equivalence relation and would all 'look similar' since it's shifting letters to the next place to get similar looking arrangements?

Comment: @happysaint Yes, shifting letters around obviously corresponds to rotating the bracelet ... which means it is still the same bracelet ... but whether it 'looks the same' is not clear.  And turning the order around (e.g. from ABCD to DCBA) corresponds to flipping the bracelet ... so again it is still the same bracelet ... but does it 'look the same'?  So again, I would get some clarification from whoever asked you this question as to what 'look the same' is supposed to mean. My guess is as good as your guess.